# Executing an exe with parameters in nodejs

Tags: node.js, exe, spawn, execfile

I wanted to execute an exe using node js. This is how the command looks in command prompt of windows:

```
oplrun -D VersionId=3458 -de "output.dat" "Test.mod" "Test.dat"
```

This runs fine and I get the output in output.dat file. Now, I wanted to execute the same with nodejs and I used execFile for this. It runs fine if I run:

```
var execFile = require('child_process').execFile;

execFile('oplrun',['Test.mod','Test.dat'], function(err, data) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err)
        } 
        else 
        console.log(data.toString());                       
    });
```

However, if I wanted to pass the output file or version as parameter, it does not execute and I am not getting any error as well. Here is the code:

```
var execFile = require('child_process').execFile;

var path ='D:\\IBM\\ILOG\SAMPLE\\output.dat';

execFile('oplrun', ['-de',path],['Test.mod','Test.dat'], function(err, data) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err)
        } 
        else 
        console.log(data.toString());                       
    });
```

How do I pass the parameters if I need pass something like -D VersionId=1111 or -de output.dat.

Thank you,
Ajith

Comment: you can all the parameter in same array as comma separated.
`['-de',path, 'Test.mod','Test.dat']`

Comment: Getting the below error: execFile('oplrun', ['-de' path, 'Test.mod','Test.dat'], function(err, data) {
                          ^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The signature of `execFile()` is shown in the [Node docs](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execfile_file_args_options_callback) as:

***file[, args][, options][, callback]***

As you are not providing any options, you should be passing a single array, as in your first example.

```
execFile('oplrun', ['-de', 'output.dat', 'Test.mod','Test.dat'], function(err, data) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err)
        } 
        else 
        console.log(data.toString());                       
    });
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried that. But that doesn't work. Here is the error:
{ [Error: Command failed: Unknown option: -de output.dat
] killed: false, code: 10, signal: null }

Comment: Thanks a lot Duncan. That's working fine. Appreciate your help.